# class name usage in one header file without including class definition header file

Tags: c++, class

Is it possible to use class A in 1.h file without including 2.h file in it (like underlying snippet code)?

File 1.h

```
class A;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> something;
```

File 2.h

```
class A{
...
}
```

Comment: Why is including `2.h` in `1.h` a problem? - that sort of thing is what headers are used for, typically.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. But you must include both 2.h and 1.h in each C/C++ file. The compiler essentially copies the contents of the .h files with each #include. This is not a very common practice, however.

Comment: The order of the #includes may matter. Here you essentially have a forward declaration, so it may be ok to include either order.

Comment: If the order of `#include`s matters the headers are badly designed. Each header should stand on its own.